# how can i divide one string, (ex:-$x="hello/welcome" ;)to two variable in php

Tags: php, html, string, variables

consider bellow variable x.is there any method to separate this to two parts at the "slash" and assign them to two variable in php. there should be only the slash between two words.

```
<?php
    $x="hello/welcome";
?>
```

Comment: use `explode('/', $x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$x="hello/welcome";
$a = explode("/", $x);

// $a[0] = "hello"
// $a[1] = "welcome"

?>
```

Is that helpful?

Comment: than you sir. that works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use explode and preg_split both .Try this:-

```
<?php
    $x="hello/welcome";
    $array = explode("/", $x);
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($array);
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
    $x="hello/welcome";
    $y = preg_split('^/^',$x);
    print_r($y);
?>
```

In both condition output is:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => welcome
)
```

Comment: Seems to be ok, but IMHO there is no need to use regex :)

Comment: I just gave examples. that's it.:)

Comment: Regex would be poor solution here.  No need for additional regex overhead here when this is simple string manipulation problem.